# Finding a basis for V from a list of given vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$$V=\mathbb{R}^3 $$

and the set of vectors is given by 
$$[(1,1,-1),(2,0,1),(-1,1,-2),(1,2,1)]$$

If I understand this correctly, I need to choose a basis such that you can use different combinations of the vectors in the basis to for $(x,y,z)$ such that $x,y,z$ are part of the Real numbers.

I can do this question with enough time by trying different combinations of vectors but I was curious if there was a simpler approach to this question.

Comment: You could check linear dependence of the vectors. If there are 3 vectors linear independent and they span $V$, they form a basis.

Comment: Hint: Try to do the row echelon form, when you write the vectors as columns in a matrix.

Comment: I took the first 3 vectors and put them into a matrix as columns and then I was able to make it into row echelon form. So this means they are independent correct? How do I now check to see if it spans V and can be used a basis of V?

Comment: if your matrix has rank3 you are done. otherwise they are dependent.

Comment: the first 3 vectors do not span V.

Comment: how do I go about finding a set of vectors here that are independent and also span V? no one seems to be able to answer that so far. I know how to prove independence but I don't know how to prove that they span V

Comment: It is known that the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is $3$. This means that $3$ linearly independent vectors necessarily span $\mathbb{R}^3$. So really your goal is just to find $3$ linearly independent vectors from the list.